# error in importing SQL dump file to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I tried to import sql dump file provided to phpmyadmin. But I get error reports. I don't know what to do. Please help.

```
Error
Static analysis:

7 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "MySQL" at position 0)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "dump" at position 6)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10.13" at position 11)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "Distrib" at position 18)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "5.5" at position 26)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near ".35" at position 29)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "for" at position 34)
SQL query:

MySQL dump 10.13 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */

MySQL said: Documentation

# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

/*!40101 SET @O' at line 1
```

Comment: There's often commented lines at the end of a dump file generated by PhpMyAdmin. Try to open your dump and delete those lines to see if it works. 
However, it's possible that when you generated your dump file, PHP goes timeout. In this case, you could have HTML tags in your dump.

Comment: dump file is a total mess. some other guy provided it to me.. but it seems like I managed to get some of the tables imported.